# Magento 2: How to send newsletter on defined time?

Tags: cron, newsletter, magento2.2.7, newsletter-subscriber

I create one newsletter template and try to send customer , i also run the ***cron*** but customer not get newsletter,

please help me how can i do that? In screenshot you can see status is Not sent., please help me
[image]

Comment: Can you add cron code to explain how you are running it

Comment: Also check status of your cron job in cron_schedule table

Comment: I use this command to run cron php bin/magento cron:run @Ajwad Taqvi

Comment: In cron_schedule table which name is created for the newsletter @Ajwad Taqvi

Comment: Your job_code in cron_schedule table should be one which you specified in crontab.xml <job instance="Vendor\Module\Cron\MyJob" method="execute" name="your_custom_job_code_here">